# How to genrate multiple instances for related objects in model Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have two models one is *Resident* and other is *Bill*.

Bills--> **belongs_to:residents**

Residents-->**has_many:bills**

> How can I generate bills for all residents?

like after clicking the generate now button . there must be bills created for every resident.
Bills will be created using three  models

> **leave Model-->** belongs_to:residents
>
> **attributes-->** *start_date:datetime,end_date:datetime*
>
> > > **rate_card Model-->** belongs_to:hostel
> > >
> > > **attributes-->** *diet:integer,charge1:int,charge2:intcharge3:int*
> > >
> > > **Account Model-->** belongs_to:resident
> > >
> > > **attributes-->** fine:int,**leaves:difference of end-start date from leave   table**
>
> **bills Model-->** belongs_to:resident
>
> **attributes-->** From_date:date,to_date:date,payable_amount:int,is_paid:bool

bill contains a payable amount  which can be generated using formula:

**payable amount: 30*diet+charge1+charge2+charge3+fine*leaves**

*how should I create bills now for each and every resident??*
I need an idea  for **create** method thanks !!

Help me out plz.. xD

Comment: `Resident.all.each { |resident| resident.bills.create }`?

Comment: All residents must have bill,if admin presses that genrate bill button, which will be work from create method.! @sipkermann

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you just want to create instances you can do something like this:

```
bills = Resident.all.map {|resident| resident.bills.create }
```

and get an array of created bills.

Comment: This works but will use a lot of memory if `residents` is a large table. Consider using `Resident.find_each { |resident| resident.bills.create }` if the resulting collection of newly created bills is not needed.

Answer (score -2):

I think it wants to generate bills for all residents:

```
Resident.all.each do |r|
  bill = Bill.new({:resident_id => r.id, :amount => value, :description => "Yadda yadda"})
  bill.save
end
```

It should make sure it adds the right attributes, seems it is probably passing bill info as params to the controller.